# DOM Elements Convert to Integer and converting them into a total time amount - Hour / Minutes parseFloat

Tags: javascript, calculation

So I have a website logged idea and I am trying to get all the minutes & hours and then create total time.

Here is the site:

https://e013g.csb.app/

and here is the codesand box:

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-lalande-e013g?file=/src/index.js

As you can see I get the minutes and try to convert it to parseFloat and then try and it all up but there is where I am stuck.

```
const mins = document.querySelectorAll('.minutes');

// console.log(mins.value.innerText);

//var totalMinutes = 0;

mins.forEach(min => {

    const convertMins = parseFloat(min.innerHTML);
    // console.log(`convertMins: ${convertMins}`);

     const calculate = min + convertMins;
    //const calculate = convertMins + convertMins;
    console.log(calculate);

    // const minutes = min.innerHTML;
    // console.log(`Minutes: ${minutes}`);


    //console.log(min.innerText);
});
```

If anyone could offer guidance I would be really grateful.

Thank you,

Dave.

P.S I have asked on Reddit here too: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/hlktfs/getting_all_minutes_and_hours_and_converting_them/

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Thank you to Pedro for the assistance here is the whole solution should anyone want to do this:

```
//Minutes
const mins = document.querySelectorAll(".minutes");

var totalMinutes = 0;

mins.forEach(min => {
  const convertMins = parseFloat(min.innerHTML);
  totalMinutes = totalMinutes + convertMins;
});

console.log(totalMinutes);

//Hours
const hours = document.querySelectorAll(".hours");

var totalHours = 0;

hours.forEach(hour => {
  const convertHours = parseFloat(hour.innerHTML);
  console.log(`Hours: ${convertHours}`);

  const newMins = convertHours * 60;
  console.log(`new mins: ${newMins}`);

  //  totalHours = totalHours + convertHours;
  totalHours = totalHours + newMins;
});

console.log(`Total Hours ${totalHours}`);

//Then add the lot

const addTotal = totalMinutes + totalHours;
console.log(`This is the total time: ${addTotal}`);

//Then Convert The Lot

function time_convert(addTotal) {
  var hours = Math.floor(addTotal / 60);
  var minutes = addTotal % 60;
  return `${hours} hrs : ${minutes} Minutes`;
}

// console.log(time_convert(161));

const headingTotal = document.querySelector(".totalTime");
console.log(headingTotal);

headingTotal.innerText = time_convert(addTotal);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shortest way is using `reduce`:

```
const mins = document.querySelectorAll('.minutes');

var totalMinutes = mins.reduce((sum, min) => {
    const convertMins = parseFloat(min.innerHTML);
    return sum + convertMins;
}, 0);

console.log(totalMinutes);
```

But in case this is complicated for you, here is a solution using `forEach`:

```
const mins = document.querySelectorAll('.minutes');

var totalMinutes = 0;

mins.forEach(min => {
    const convertMins = parseFloat(min.innerHTML);
    totalMinutes = totalMinutes + convertMins;
});

console.log(totalMinutes);
```

Comment: Thank you for that Pedro, that is exactly what I needed and now I have finished what I wanted to do as you can see in the question above. I just needed a refresher on how to do it and you came to my aid, so thank you sir!

Comment: Pedro as I am new I can not upvote your answer but I have marked it as the answer and thanked :)